# error while installing dj-rest-auth inside google cloud vm and i created a virtualenv

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am inside SSH window of VM
I created a virtal environment using command :virtualenv -p python3.8 venv
now i try to install dj-rest-auth using command pip install dj-rest-auth and i am receiving error
Building wheels for collected packages: dj-rest-auth
Building wheel for dj-rest-auth (setup.py) ... error

But it allow me to install using sudo pip install dj-rest-auth but while running my django project it is not recognising and i am receiving module not found error

Python 3.8.3 is the version

can any one tell me the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

if we create a virtual environment having python installed inside VM using command python3 -m venv myenv then no error reeceived and all librarie got installed